# Is there a shortcut for changing the value a Layer's Fill similar to configuring its opacity

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, transparency, fill

So to change a layers opacity value using the keyboard you would use the numeric keys. But being how close it is in proximity you would think there would be something similar for change a layer's fill. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold shift while pressing the number.

Comment: @CarlEdwards no problem. Don't be afraid to mash buttons, or look in the keyboard shortcut list. You can't really damage anything. Also remember to mark the answer correct so it doesn't look like an unanswered question. Welcome to the community.